# display.mode = 'showcase' in shinyApp() call - no code shown

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to be able to use display.mode = 'showcase' in an app run with the `shinyApp()` function call. According to the docs I should be able to pass any arguments that go `runApp()` through the `options` argument. The showcase mode works (the window is split) but it does not show the code.  What's interesting is that if I run `runExample("01_hello")` everything works fine. I'm using shiny 1.0.5.

Code:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Sample App"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("data", label = "Data set",
                  choices = c("mtcars", "iris"))
    ),

    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("table")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  data <- reactive({
    get(input$data, 'package:datasets')
  })

  output$table <- renderTable({
    head(data())
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server, options = list(display.mode = 'showcase'))
```

Output:
[image: shinyApp() with showcase mode not showing code]

Comment: The example app uses app.R construct and keys the display.mode from the DESCRIPTION file in the same directory. If you save this code as app.R in a directory and include a DESCRIPTION file with metadata for the display.mode it will work. Works for me that way.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue. I had the app.R file and created the DESCRIPTION file using notepad but couldn't deploy a shinyApp with the code. Then I copied the DESCRIPTION file from `shiny\examples\01_hello` and noticed this:

[image]

Turns out my file had a TXT extension, so Shiny wasn't reading it as a metadata file. Once I used the correct DESCRIPTION file (which you can edit using notepad), everything worked out fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of an addendum to Gus_est's answer, since I had the same problem and wasn't able to get it run right from there.

Create a file inside the directory your `app.R`-file resides in, e.g. a txt-file. Write into the file what display mode is to be used using *Debian Control file* format. In our case it would look like that (`Title` is not necessary):

```
Title: My App
DisplayMode: Showcase
```

Then rename the file `DESCRIPTION` without providing a file ending. Ignore the warning.

When you run the app now, it will always be in display mode "showcase", you can override this only inside the `runApp()`-statement. So I find the documentation to be misleading.

Answer (score -1):

Check your current working directory. This problem seems to occur, if the working directory is not set to the folder with the app code.

Comment: This is not a complete answer and should be a comment. Also the problem is old and already solved, although the OP didn't mark the right answer.